# Perl XML::LibXML: findnode vs. findvalue vs. find - what's the difference?

Tags: perl, xpath, libxml2

I am using [`XML::LibXML`](https://metacpan.org/module/XML::LibXML), and I simply need to get a count of the nodes specified by an XPath expression.

Using either of the first two code lines below yields what I'm looking for. I can use the `count` XPath function with either `findvalue` or `find` but not `findnodes` (yes, I know, because it returns a list).

```
my $node_cnt = $dom->findvalue("count($xpath_str)");  # WORKS!
my $node_cnt = $dom->find("count($xpath_str)");       # WORKS!
my @node_cnt = $dom->findnodes("count($xpath_str)");  # count doesn't work!
```

Which leads me to a general nagging question: 
What's the difference between the three `find` types? In the documentation, it says:

```
$string = $node->findvalue($xpath)
$result = $node->find($xpath)
@nodes  = $node->findnodes($xpath_expression)
```

1. Is there really a difference between the argument `$xpath_expression` vs. just `$xpath` in the documentation?
2. For the two returning a scalar, what's the difference?

I'm trying to understand the significance of using one find type over the other - thank you!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The difference is the type of value that the methods return.

- `findnodes` is used to return a list of nodes. If the method is called in list context then it returns a list of objects of the appropriate type, such as `XML::LibXML::Element`, `XML::LibXML::Text` etc. If it is called in scalar context then it returns a single `XML::LibXML::NodeList` object that contains the same information.

  It *cannot* be used to return an arbitrary expression, for instance `$dom->findnodes('42')` will return nothing. You can only ever get a list document nodes from this method.
- `findvalue` is used to return a single text or numeric *value*, i.e. not an XML node. If you pass an XPath expression that evaluates to a node list then it converts that list to text by concatenating all the text nodes within any of the nodes in the list.
- `find` can return anything. It will return a node list as an `XML::LibXML::NodeList` object, a numeric value as an `XML::LibXML::Number` object, a string literal as a `XML::LibXML::Literal` object etc. Unlike `findnodes`, it *always* returns a single scalar value, even if called in list context.

  I have never chosen to use `find`. It looks like it is intended as a catch all when you don't know what sort of result to expect.

For instance, you would probably want to write `my $nrecs = $dom->findvalue('count(/root/record)')` to get the number of records within the root element. `$nrecs` would be a simple perl numeric value.

On the other hand, to get a *list* of those records, you would use  `my @records = $dom->findnodes('/root/record')`. Now `@records` contains a number of `XML::LibXML::Element` objects.

In your examples,

```
my $node_cnt = $dom->findvalue("count($xpath_str)");  # WORKS!
```

this sets `$node_cnt` to a simple Perl number, while this

```
my $node_cnt = $dom->find("count($xpath_str)");  # WORKS!
```

sets `$node_cnt` to a `XML::LibXML::Number` object, that happens to stringify (when you print it) to the same as the previous statement. Prove this for yourself by printing `print ref $node_cnt` in both cases.

Then

```
my @node_cnt = $dom->findnodes("count($xpath_str)");  # count doesn't work!
```

fails because the XPath `count` evaluates to a number, not an XML node (it isn't part of the XML tree). There is no way of converting numbers to nodes, so the result is an empty list. If it was the other way round, and we had called `findvalue` on an expression that evaluated to a node list, then there is a vaguely sensible way of converting to a text value and `findvalue` does its best and returns the concatenation of all the text nodes contained by the nodes in the list.

Comment: thank you, thank you... that helps a lot!!!!  I too will stay away from 'find' and use either 'findvalue' or 'findnodes' accordingly.